# Python: Type error

Tags: python, list, append, typeerror, keyword-argument

```
def main():

    COUNT = 1
    food = []

    n = int(input("Enter the number of items on your grocery list.\n"))

    for i in range(1, n+1):
        food.append = (input("What is item #" + str(COUNT) + " on your list?\n", sep=""))
        COUNT = COUNT + 1

main()
```

I'm trying to add the user's input to the "food" list. So far I have this but when I run it, it gives me a error: TypeError: input() takes no keyword arguments

any suggestions?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but I do not think you need the variable `COUNT`, instead `i` can be used in place of `COUNT`.

Answer (score 6):

`input()` doesn't take any keyword arguments. `sep=""` is for the print function.

Also, don't expect `food.append =` to do anything, `append` is a function, you must do `food.append(input(...`

Comment: ok that worked, now when I run the program, when it prompts for me to enter the items, it says "None" first. Not sure where this is coming from...I'm guessig because I have an empty list??

Comment: @user2251238 Please tell me the line of code where the `None` appears

Comment: @user2251238 No, tell me the changed line please

Answer (score 0):

`input()` should go by itself, preceded by `print("Enter whatever...")`. More on `input()`  can be found at the [Python website](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input).

Answer (score 0):

just remove the sep="" from your code